# Adding a confidence interval to deal with noisy measurements

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, measurement

I have a formula and I am not sure how the author of this paper got to that formula. Im working on an algorithm that can filter out ground points from a Point cloud. The author describes the following formula:[image: Formula Erosion]

the h_max is later replaced with => h_max(d) = 0.3*d (d = distance between two points)
Now what he writes is the following: "In the usual case of noisy measurements, one would like to add a confidence interval. If one would allow that 5% of the
terrain points with a standard deviation s may be rejected, the filter function becomes:    h_max(d) = 0.3*d + 1.65 * sqrt(2) * sigma"    This it the point where i get lost. I have no clue how the author acutally gets to this formula. I do understand the 1.65 and the sigma but not why there is a sqrt(2).    Does anyone have a clue on how the author got to this formula?  Here is the original paper: [Vossselmans Modified Slope based Filter](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228719860_Slope_based_filtering_of_laser_altimetry_data)

Comment: Is the "distance" the Euclidean distance in two dimensions?

Comment: Yes the Euclideean distance but in three dimensions.